# Should I set the locale to `C` when matching a range of numbers?

Tags: shell, posix, locale, pattern-matching

If I wanted to search for lines in a file that contain `a` or `b` or `c` or `d` I would run

```
LC_COLLATE=C grep -E '[a-d]' file_to_search
```

or

```
LC_ALL=C grep -E '[a-d]' file_to_search
```

If I fail to set the locale to `C` in the examples above, I risk matching characters that are not `a` or `b` or `c` or `d`.

If I am searching for a range of numbers

```
grep -E '[1-5]' file_to_search
```

is it still important for me to set the locale to `C`?